Is there an existing method to store a large set of states (900+ flags/numbers) for a single form page that it can persist for several days?
I just need a pointer or two in the right direction. I made a WP page with a large set of checkbox items to mark a set of tasks as completed, with the intent to also implement counters for a few other tasks. The data scale is about 900 flags or numbers. I have been searching for some kind of best practice within the framework to persist the state of the flags or numbers for many days. I wanted this to behave as an extended session without having to require a user login and, if possible, operate completely client-side.
As I thought about how to do this, I created a basic framework to achieve it with cookies. However, I was using the cookie as a data store, and this scale was far too large. Besides, this seemed a the wrong way to do this from the start.
I think I just need specific search terms to research and direct my effort. Can a store be created on the server that can be tied to a user session without login? Is there a layer of local storage that can be accessed by javascript the same as cookies, persistent for several days, and cleared or expired?
Thank you for your attention.

can you make your question specific/concrete? You can ask how to do something but you can't ask for general advice/discussion as this isn't a forum, the sites set up so that you have to pick an answer as the "correct" answer. You're also limiting yourself by asking in just WordPress circles, what you want sounds like a cookies and javascript problem that would apply even to static HTML

IndexedDB should be what you are searching for. However, that's not really a WordPress topic.
